# Filter one list android depending on other list

Tags: java, android, listview, filter

I have 2 lists with in 2 different adapters. The first list displays categries, the second one names. Something like:

```
List 1
- Dogs
- Cats

List 2
- Pluto (Dogs)
- Oliver (Cats)
- Billo (Cats)
```

The second list includes the category (an hidden textview in the item.xml). What I would like to do is that on click of item "`Dogs`" the second list should show me only the item "`Pluto`", or tapping on "`Cats`" the second list should show "`Oliver`" and "`Billo`".

I tried this scenario in following way; The first list with its adapter

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, categories);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and then the item click

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            String itemValue = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                            getAdapter().getFilter().filter(itemValue);
                        }
                    });
```

This `getAdapter().getFilter().filter(itemValue)` should filter the second list but it doesn't work. When i tap one of the item the items of the second list disappear. But, if I try in this way

```
getAdapter().getFilter().filter("Pluto");
```

it works. And it filters the second list. I can't understand why doesn't work using the categories

Comment: you should post the filter code. according to your description, onItemClick will call getAdapter().getFilter().filter("Dog"), obviously it will not filter ("Pluto"), as Dog is not in your second list.

Comment: @AIMINPAN it is in the second list

Comment: @pskink because i can't use it in this project

Comment: @pskink do you have an example?

Comment: I think the problem may be ClassCast. Could you please print the out put of getAdapter().getFilter().filter(itemValue). It should be in string.

Comment: @Jatin itemValue is a string

Comment: Ok @End.Game, So if you click over Dogs of first list, you get output of 'listView.getItemAtPosition(position)' as 'Dogs' ?

Comment: @Jatin yes, exactly

Comment: @pskink it passes Dogs as well